# Error building native image with gluonfx-maven-plugin 1.0.14

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I'm trying to build a native image using:

**GraalVM:** 22.2.0

**GluonFx maven Plugin:** 1.0.14

And I get the following error:

```
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [1/7] Initializing...                                                                                    (0.0s @ 0.42GB)                                                                         
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Fatal error: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.graal.HeapFeature (in unnamed module @0x499d741f) cannot access class com.oracle.svm.core.SubstrateOptions (in module org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder) because module org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder does not export com.oracle.svm.core to unnamed module @0x499d741f                                                                                      
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.graal.HeapFeature.isInConfiguration(HeapFeature.java:65)                                                                                                  
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.registerFeature(FeatureHandler.java:183)                                                                             
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.registerFeatures(FeatureHandler.java:128)                                                                            
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:838)                                                                
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:561)                                                                           
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:521)                                                                             
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:407)                                                          
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:585)                                                               
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)                                                                
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                         
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]                         1.7s (8.7% of total time) in 17 GCs | Peak RSS: 1.48GB | CPU load: 2.23                                                                                                  
[Thu Jul 28 13:31:42 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide me

**Updated:**
By the suggestion of @peterz I've downgraded the version of GraalVM, now running with 22.1.0, and the error is different:

```
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [1/7] Initializing...                                                                                    (0.0s @ 0.56GB)                                                                         
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Error: ImageSingletons.add must not overwrite existing key com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.ProtectionDomainSupport                                                                                       
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Existing value: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.ProtectionDomainSupport@1ff463bb                                                                                                                         
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] New value: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.ProtectionDomainSupport@3b9c9b8b                                                                                                                              
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: ImageSingletons.add must not overwrite existing key com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.ProtectionDomainSupport                                            
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Existing value: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.ProtectionDomainSupport@1ff463bb                                                                                                                         
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] New value: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.ProtectionDomainSupport@3b9c9b8b                                                                                                                              
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:72)                                                                                                                               
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ImageSingletonsSupportImpl$HostedManagement.doAdd(ImageSingletonsSupportImpl.java:109)                                                                              
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ImageSingletonsSupportImpl.add(ImageSingletonsSupportImpl.java:39)                                                                                                  
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.nativeimage.ImageSingletons.add(ImageSingletons.java:73)                                                                                                      
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ProtectionDomainFeature.afterRegistration(ProtectionDomainFeature.java:48)                                                                                          
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$setupNativeImage$14(NativeImageGenerator.java:832)                                                                                      
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:74)                                                                                                               
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:832)                                                                                                
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:555)                                                                                                           
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:515)                                                                                                             
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:407)                                                                                          
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:585)                                                                                               
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)                                                                                                
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:615)                                                                                       
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                         
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]                         1.7s (9.6% of total time) in 16 GCs | Peak RSS: 1.39GB | CPU load: 3.91                                                                                                  
[Thu Jul 28 14:32:34 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
```

Comment: It seems gluonfx plugin was released in June, while GraalVM 22.2 is just a couple of days old -- the plugin might need some updating to accommodate the newest changes. In the meantime maybe GraalVM 22.1 will work for you

Comment: Thanks for the remark @peterz I've downgraded the version, and updated the ticket